# passing pointer to const char in function call resets it to NULL

Tags: c, pointers, null, char, constants

I'm calling a function that takes a pointer to const char, sets this pointer to a constant, static string, and returns it.
However, after returning, the pointer is NULL!

```
static const char *test = "my text";

int check(const char *s) {
  s = test;
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  const char *s = NULL;
  if (check(s) == 0) printf("%s", s);
  return 0;
}
```

returns "(null)" instead of "my text".

Answer (score 4):

It's because you pass the pointer *by value*, i.e. it's copied, and in the function you only change the copy.

Since C doesn't have proper references, you can emulate passing by reference by passing a pointer. So you have to pass a *pointer to the pointer*. This can be accomplished with the address-of operator `&` (and of course with the proper modifications of the function).

Answer (score 1):

As a clarification for the process that is going on in your current code, take a look at this similar example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test = 5;

int check( int qwe ) {
    qwe = test;
    return 0;
}

int main( ) {
    int asd = 1;
    if ( check( asd ) == 0 ) printf( "%d", asd );
    return 0;
}
```

Similar to what you had, this code will also be printing `1`, instead of `5`. It could be that you aren't sure why this would print `1`, so let me explain the process here step by step to make sure. *Feel free to skip this part if you have no issues about this:*

- **1 -** A local variable with the type of `int` called `asd` will be created in the function `main`
- **2 -** A memory location with enough much size will be allocated for this variable, automatically
- **3 -** This location will be filled with the data `1`
- **4 -** Function `check` will be called with the argument `asd`, that carries the data `1`
- **5 -** A local variable with the type of `int` called `qwe` will be created in the function `check`
- **6 -** A memory location... same as **2**
- **7 -** This location will be filled with the data provided by the parameter `asd`, that is, `1`
- **8 -** Then this location will be replaced with the data provided by the variable `test`, that is, `5`
- **9 -** `return` encounter will free all the automatically allocated memory locations

  - **9.1** Memory location of `qwe` will be freed
- **10 -** Back inside the `main`, the condition is fulfilled, therefore the `printf` will be issued, which will print what the memory location for `asd` has, that is `1`

You see, the memory location for `asd` has not been changed; only the newly created memory location for the variable `qwe` has been changed, which then got also freed. There is no reason for the value `5` to be printed in this scenario, just like `"my text"` to be printed in yours.

In this example here, what you could do to print `5` is:

- **1 -** to pass the address of the memory location, allocated for the variable `asd`
- **2 -** access and change the contents of that memory location

This is the address of the memory location for the variable `asd`:

```
&asd;
```

And this is how you can pass the address of that location:

```
check( &asd );
```

Now, since `&asd` is not a variable of type `int`, but rather a variable of type `int *` (pointer to an integer), we have to change the parameter type that `check` accepts as well, like this:

```
int check( int * qwe ) { ... }
```

`qwe` will then hold the address to the memory location for the variable `asd`. To access the contents, called as *dereferencing*, you can do this:

```
*qwe;   // <-- contents of the address that qwe holds
```

And to change the contents:

```
*qwe = test;
```

So at its final stage, it should look like this, if we want the contents of `asd` to be changed for real:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test = 5;

int check( int * qwe ) {    // added an asterisk (*)
    *qwe = test;        // here as well
    return 0;
}

int main( ) {
    int asd = 1;
    if ( check( &asd ) == 0 ) printf( "%d", asd );  // added an ampersand (&)
    return 0;
}
```

All this applies for the code you have. `const` in front of the `char` doesn't have any play in your case, because it just makes the `char`s being pointed at to be constant, not the pointer itself. So if your code were to get changed like the following, it would do what you desire:

```
static const char *test = "my text";

int check( const char **s ) {   // added an asterisk (*)
    *s = test;      // here as well
    return 0;
}

int main( ) {
    const char *s = NULL;
    if ( check( &s ) == 0 ) printf( "%s", s );  // added an ampersand (&)
    return 0;
}
```

But if there were `const`s behind the `int`s in my code, that would be a problem. It would be a problem at the stage where I would attempt to assign `*qwe` with `test`, because then I would have been defining the `qwe` as a pointer to a constant integer. Not an issue on your case, because you aren't trying to change `**s`, just `*s`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize that the variable `s` defined in `main` and the variable `s` in the function `check` are two different variables. When you call `check` in `main` and pass `s` to it, then the value of `s` in `main` is copied to the function argument `s`. Any changes made to `s` in the function is not visible in `main`. In fact, the function argument `s`  ceases to exist after `check` returns because it has function scope. If you want the change to be reflected in `main`, then you should pass the address of `s` to `check`, instead of passing the value of `s`, and change the function definition accordingly.

```
static const char *test = "my text";

int check(const char **s) {
  *s = test;
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  const char *s = NULL;
  if(check(&s) == 0)  // pass the address of s to check
      printf("%s", s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Address of pointer and you would be good.

The way you wrote your code, pointer's copy is modified in the called function not the pointer itself.

=============================================================

```
#include<stdio.h>

static const char *test = "my text";

int check(const char **s) {
  *s = test;
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  const char *s = NULL;
  if (check(&s) == 0) printf("%s", s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
int check (int i)
{
    i = 2;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    if (check (3) == 0) printf("hello");
}
```

You wouldn't expect this to somehow change the value of `3` would you?

Now look at your code:

```
if (check(s) == 0) printf("%s", s);
```

Expecting your code to somehow change the value of `s` into something else is just as unreasonable.